# Wrote a program to get the binary output of a decimal, and the result is inverted

Tags: c

Below is the program for my assignment. All of it was given except the printing and logic. I searched many videos about it and did what they did, but 15's binary is 1111 and the result was 0000

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Function to convert decimal to binary
// The function is void type so, print the result inside the function

void decimal2Binary(int dec) {
    // array to store binary number
    int binaryNumber[32];

    // Your logic goes here
    // fill out the binaryNumber
    // i to increment the loop and terminate
    int i = 0;
    // We are interested in positive numbers for now
    while (dec > 0) {
        // Please add your logic to build the binary array
        binaryNumber[i] = dec%2;
        dec = dec/2;
        i++;
    }

    // Print the binary array.
    printf("Binary: ");
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        printf("%d",binaryNumber[i]);
    }
    
}

// The main function goes here
// The main function calls the decimal2Binary

int main() {
    int decimal = 15;
    
    printf("Decimal: %d equal to ", decimal);
    decimal2Binary(decimal);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d",binaryNumber[i]);` -> `printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);`

Answer (score 1):

**DECIMAL TO BINARY (RECURSIVE):**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find(int dec_num)
{
    if (dec_num == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (dec_num % 2 + 10 *
            find(dec_num / 2));
}

int main()
{
    int decimal_number;
    scanf("%d", &decimal_number);
    printf("%d", find(decimal_number));
    return 0;
}
```

**DECIMAL TO BINARY (ITERATIVE):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
long dec_to_bin(int decimalnum){

    int binarynum = 0;
    int mod, place = 1;

while(decimalnum != 0){
    mod = decimalnum % 2;
    decimalnum = decimalnum/2;
    binarynum = binarynum + (mod*place);
    place = place*10;
    }
    return binarynum;

}
int main() {
    int decimalnum;
    scanf("%d", &decimalnum);
    printf("enter a decimal number:\n %ld", dec_to_bin(decimalnum));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer.